# Koin is it possible to get an instance by class' name?

Tags: koin

I have 2 separate modules in an Android project.
One is the application and the other contains common functions.
The second module knows nothing about the first

I'd like to get in the second module (common functions) an instance of a class declared in the first module. The class is derived from an abstract class declared in the second module

I know the name of a class, but not the type. Is it possible to get an instance of a class from Koin by the name of the class?

Answer (score 0):

```
val className = TripsRepository::class.getFullName()
val definition = getKoin()._scopeRegistry._rootScopeDefinition?.definitions?.firstOrNull { it.primaryType.getFullName() == className }
if(definition != null){
     val instance = getKoin().get(definition.primaryType) as AbstractNetworkRepository<CommonId>
}
```

for the latest Koin's version

```
fun <T> Koin.getByClassName(className : String) : T? {
    val definition = this._scopeRegistry.rootScopeDefinition.definitions.firstOrNull { it.primaryType.getFullName() == className }
    if(definition != null){
        return this.get<T>(definition.primaryType)
    }
    return null
}
```